# attempt to compare nil with number Corona

Tags: android, sdk, lua, coronasdk, null

I'm about to finish my game, but I ran into an error:

```
attempt to compare nil with number game2.lua 444
```

I don't have a clue on how to fix this, and I've tried quite everything, with no success. I think the function `scrollSpace` is causing this, because sometimes the background would scroll at an uncontrollable speed. Here is my code:

```
function scrollSpace(self,event)
    if self.x  < -900 then
        self.x = 800
    else 
        self.x = self.x - self.speed
    end 
end
```

This controls how the stuff scroll across the screen. If you guys what more code, just reply, and I'll be happy to add the requested source. One last thing: does anyone know what the following error means:

```
attempt to compare nil with number
```

this is my file code:

```
  coin01 = display.newImage("coin02.png")
  coin01.y = 100
  coin01.x = 500
  coin01.speed = math.random(2,6)
  coin01.initY = mine1.y
  coin01.amp   = math.random(20,100)
  coin01.angle = math.random(1,360) 

 physics.addBody(coin01, "static", {density=.1,bounce=0.1, friction=.2,radius=12})
 screenGroup:insert(coin01)
 end  -- end of create scene
**print "passed"

 function scrollSpace(self,event)
 if self.x  < -900 then
  self.x = 800
else 
self.x = self.x - self.speed
 end 
    end**
function scene:enterScene(event)

coin01.enterFrame = coins
Runtime:addEventListener ("enterFrame",coin01)  
  end 
  function scene:exitScene(event)
 ***storyboard . purgeScene ("start")
 story board . purgeScene ("restart")***
  Runtime:removeEventListener ("enterFrame",coin01)

  end

   function scene:destroyScene(event)

end

scene:addEventListener("createScene",scene)
scene:addEventListener("enterScene",scene) 
scene:addEventListener("exitScene",scene) 
scene:addEventListener("destroyScene",scene) 

return scene
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Attempt to compare nil with number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17625414/attempt-to-compare-nil-with-number)

Answer (score 0):

Apperantly self.x is a nil value.. If you remove it somewhere and then listener is called in the same time, there wont be any self.x value.

You should post every line where you change/create self object. And also listener

Comment: hey guys people who are getting this error  using story Board you just need to put  storyboard . purgeScene ("start")
             story board . purgeScene ("restart")                                       in the enter scene event  hope this help people out